# OSM: Osmfilter: Filter by ID

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to use Osmfilter for extracting specific relations by ID (and their dependent ways and nodes).

All I've found was filtering by tag/key.

Is there a way to filter by ID?

Comment: Welcome to GISSE!  Please take the site [tour].  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In osmfilter's [documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) via the OSM wiki I found a hint about the `@id` search key.

Having not tested on my own, you should find out whether that feature is that what you are looking for, and how you can define a filtering for nodes, ways or relation with its own OSM id number (because node 123456 is different from way 123456 and also from relation 123456, but all three do co-exist.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for the hint that there is no sequential id pattern for all three object types. The query for osmfilter for relations is then [--keep-relations="@id=123456" --keep-ways= --keep-nodes=].